# Multiple Applications Same Trunk? Best Practice help required

Tags: tfs, version-control

I did a check if this has been asked before but the closest I found were questions around a single application with different branches for clients.

What is the best strategy for handling multiple applications in version control?  Say I have 5 completely separate applications that can require changes at any point.  Do I put them all under the same main trunk (origin/master if you will) then branch off as required or should they all get their own trunk?

Let me know if it's not described well and I can add more information.

Comment: In short. Separate trunks. 
If an application has it's own release cycle always put it in a different trunk. It will make release management/building and testing easier to handle. No reason to put them in the same trunk. If you still want to group them, some git repo systems allow grouping projects. Like for example gitlab

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should see the [Branch strategically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/branch-strategically):

> **When should the team add a branch?**
>
> You should create branches in the following situations:
>
> - When you must release code on a different schedule/cycle than the
>     existing branches.
> - When your code requires a different branch policy. If you create a
>     new branch that has the new policy, you can add strategic value to
>     your project.
> - When functionality is released to a customer and your team plans to
>     make changes that do not affect the planned release cycle.
>
> You should not create a branching for each user story because it
>   creates a high integration cost. Although makes branching easy, the
>   overhead of managing branches can become significant if you have many
>   branches.

In you scenario, It's based on how do you want to manage the applications, different schedule/cycle ... then you need to track in another branch as David mentioned above. And if the size of applications are very large, you can even version control them separately in new team project.

This article for your reference : [Branching and Merging: Ten Pretty-Good Practices](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/opinion/opinion-pieces/branching-and-merging-ten-pretty-good-practices/)

Comment: Many of the applications are in use but do not have active development. They will be on a pure feature release or bug fix cycle.  I would expect to put out, at best, bi-annual releases.  It's really just this all in one trunk and branch as need or each with their own trunk and an origin / release / develop branch for each. That's where I'm getting stuck on whats best.

Comment: Also worth noting, effort involved is not relevant. I'm looking to do whats best.

Comment: @grimchamp I think it's better to speparate them as you mentioned they are completely separate applications and have their own feature release/cicle. Of cause if the applications are all small projects, you can track them in one trunk, they will not take much more spaces and other resources, but you need to take more attention to exclude other resources when do actions for the specific application.